# Do those who are saved still face judgement?

Tags: soteriology

Do those who are saved still face judgement?

Comment: can you add more details to clarify from which denomination/theology you'd like an answer from?

Comment: _we must all appear before the judgment seat of Christ; that every one may receive the things done in his body, according to that he hath done, whether it be good or bad._ 2 Corinthians 5:10 is an important text to consider in this regard.

Comment: Please remember that although we often assume "judgement" is always a negative thing, that's not so. A person who has done something bad and is judged will be punished, but a person who has done good and is judged will be praised.

Comment: @DJClayworth, although plenty of Christians believe that *no one* has done good (n.b. Romans 3:10). My take would be it's more like going to court and having your sentence commuted. Or acquitted because Christ is defending you. Something like that, anyway. Note also it's implied that those who are saved will be surprised by this (Matthew 25:31-46). As for the others... it's hard to repent if you don't recognize your sin.